# Angular asynchronous function

Tags: angular

```
  async onRegister(formRegister) {

    this.nbotoncito = false;
    this.spinner.show();

    if (this.ejercicio.idArea == "2") {
      console.log("ejercicios de fisica");
      await this.getTotalFisica();

    } else {
      console.log("cualquier cosa ajena a fisica");
      await this.getEjercicios_SubArea();

    }
  }
```

```
  async getTotalFisica() {

    await this.ejercicioService.getEjercicioTotalFisica().subscribe(
      res => {
         this.ejercicioTotal =   res;
        console.log("Respuesta del total de los ejercicios por FISICA: " + res);
      },
      err => console.log(err),
    );
  }
```

Before performing other actions in my **onRegister** I must have that array of exercises Total Loaded that method of **getTotalPhysics** comes from a **backend** hosted in heroku the function is as follows:

```
  getEjercicioTotalFisica(): Observable<EjercicioInterface[]> {
    console.log("Solcitando los ejercicos de fisica");
    return this.http.get<EjercicioInterface[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/exercise/fisica`);
  }
```

I must have the compulsory array of exercises Total and necessary before carrying out any type of action in onRegister, and first the subscribe within onRegister is performed before that of getTotalExercises.

I don't receive errors, I'm just **looking** to fill that **array** before any **action**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing promises and Observables.

Convert your Observable to a promise:

```
async getTotalFisica() {
  try {
    this.ejercicioTotal = await this.ejercicioService.getEjercicioTotalFisica().toPromise();
  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err),
  }
}
```

(Note the `.toPromise()` at the end)

Comment: " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) The following error throws me your code

Comment: Okay, I don't see how my code can be related to that error. It seems to be related to the actual request sent in `getEjercicioTotalFisica()`. Have a look in the Network tab of the developer console, maybe there's a clue there.